# Remove symbols by RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove next symbols :

- `\`
- `/`
- `.`
- `?`
- `:`

And tried to use next RegExp :

```
var NoUse = new RegExp("\/|\\|\:|\?","g");
...
var name = fullname.replace(NoUse,"g");
...
```

But it falls with error :

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `//|\|:|?/:` Nothing to repeat
```

How can I change this regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `RegExp` constructor, you have to double escape the backslashes:

```
new RegExp("/|\\\\|:|\\?|\\.","g");
```

And the backslash itself has to be escaped. Oh and you didn't have the period in your regex.

Otherwise, you can use a character class:

```
new RegExp("[/\\\\:?.]","g");
```

Or simply use this construct:

```
var NoUse = /[\/\\:?.]/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use character class (`[]`):

```
var name = fullname.replace(/[\\/.?:]+/g, '');
```

---

Example:

```
var fullname = 'J. Lee';
var name = fullname.replace(/[\\/.?:]+/g, '');
name # => "J Lee"
```